# TemplateDoesNotExist for base.html of each app

Tags: django, django-templates

Here's the structure of my project:

```
project_name/
    app1/
        templates/
            base.html
            app1/
                index.html
    app2/
        templates/
            base.html
            app2/
                index.html
    app3/
        templates/
            base.html
            app3/
                index.html
```

And in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates/', ],
        ...
    },
]
```

and `BASE_DIR` is defined as (the default for Django 3.2 on Windows):

```
Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

None of my `index.html` files are able to locate their own `base.html` using `{% extends 'appX/base.html'`

I get `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `base.html` templates to the `appi/templates/appi/` directories, so:

```
project_name/
    app1/
        templates/
            app1/
                base.html
                index.html
    app2/
        templates/
            app2/
                base.html
                index.html
    app3/
        templates/
            app3/
                base.html
                index.html
```

This happens since Django will look to all `templates/` directories, but you are extending with `appi/base.html`. It thus will need to look for an `appi` directory in one of the `templates/` directories.